# Function is not being called after input assigns a value (Python)

Tags: python, input, integer, readfile

I have a small file with a bunch of phrases on each line. I want the user to type a number and that number will print the selected line.

```
def printSpecLine(x):
    print('started')
    with open('c:/lab/save.txt') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if i == x:
                break
    print (line)
    print('done')
    f.close()

s = int(input("Enter a number: "))
printSpecLine(s)
```

I've ran this with no errors, but the function isn't being called at all. Printing "started" (second line) didn't even occur. Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation for this is that you are not actually inputting to the prompt! There doesn't seem to be any other reason why at least the first `print` wouldn't be made.

Remember that `input()` is blocking, so until you enter your number and press `enter`, the program will be halted where it is (i.e. not call the function).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the ide i was using has a problem with raw input and integers being converted. Sublime Text 3 doesn't take python input very well. Thank you for your answer.